# How can I get the Flash_data in Redirecting method

Tags: php, codeigniter, database-connection, codeigniter-3

lets assume i have two controller and one view...... in one controller I m displaying view while on second I am running method.  which is not displaying.

**controller one**..

```
Function add_product()
      { 
       $post=$this->input->post(); 
  if($this->add->rundbFunction($post)==TRUE)
 { 
    $this->db->close(); 
     $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Product has been added 
    successfully'); 
 return redirect('Secondcontroller/add'); 
         }
```

on second **controller** function goes like this

```
           Function add(){ 
                      $this->load->view('product_veiw_page'); 
                }
```

on **View**

```
<?php if($error=$this->session->flashdata('success')): ?>
    <div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-success">
        <!-------displaying error------->
        <strong><?=$error;?></strong>

    </div>
       <!------end of end condition------->
        <?php endif?>
```

**IMPORTANT** Flash messag can be dsiplayed if and only if I call the View in Add_product function and not redirect to second controller for second method -add. call this coded in add_product(){}.

```
$this->load->view('product_veiw_page');
```

Comment: (Closing) database has nothing with sessions.

Comment: so, what to do?

Comment: this is possible in redirecting to another function but the problem is through redirection flashdata are getting expire.........

Comment: For several redirects there is `keep_flashdata()` method.

Comment: then i call it like this in View $this->session->flashdata('failled') or differentky Tpojka?

Comment: In method (request), when nyou make redirection you just prolong flashdata. You first make it with `set_flashdata('key', 'value')`. When you make redirect to `controller2/method2` you are getting that value but flash session is lost if you don't use `keep_flashdata('value')`. Tbh, I am not understand your problem quite: after you are adding product to DB (let's say over some form), you have to load some view. If it is done over AJAX, you need to echo message back. In AJAX case you don't need flash data. Just echo `ok` or `not ok` (something similar) in appropriate part of if block.

Comment: Also, you don't need to spend much on closing database because CI makes it automagically. Instead show view part where you use variables/values passed through flash data.

Comment: lets assume i have two controller and one view...... in one controller I m displaying view and second I am Using Methods.
controller one..
           Function add_product(){
         $post=$this->input->post();
     if($this->add->rundbFunction($post)==TRUE){

            $this->db->close();
     $this->session->keep_flashdata('success','Product has been added 
    successfully');
             return redirect('Secondcontroller/add');

         }
while on second control function goes like this
  Function add(){
    $this->load->view('product_veiw_page');
   }

Comment: Please edit your opening question with this data and forma it into code tags there to be readable to everyone.

Comment: is it comprehensible now?

Comment: Which URL you are calling in step 1?

Comment: return redirect('Secondcontroller/add');... add function is in another controller

Comment: How do you get on first link? Where is view of that? Help us to help you. That return redirect should stay in question code. Spit everything you have there to avoid yourself of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem#answer-66378) trap.